# call a function where there is existing on the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use codeigniter mvc for my project, im making a unique id logger that if there id exist it will call the unique generator function again. how to call the function inside model

heres my model:

```
function getGenLogsId() {
    $matches = '12345';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbllogs WHERE logsid LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($matches)."%'";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        // call function again
    } else {
        // if not exist save!!
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the function is on controller

Answer (score 0):

you can call `$this->getGenLogsId();`

```
function getGenLogsId() {
    $matches = '12345';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbllogs WHERE logsid LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($matches)."%'";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->getGenLogsId();
    } else {
        // if not exist save!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if it's in the same controller use :

```
 $this->function();
```

if it's in the model:

```
 $this->load->model('ModelName');
 $this->ModelName->function();
```

**NOTE**

if it's in the controller it's a good practice to make it a private function so no direct call is allowed to that function by starting the function name with _

Example:

```
function _test(){

}
```

Comment: the above function is in his model... he needs to return some value from his model and on the basis of that he can go ahead